# Variable Scope will be exceeded

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I've got follow source code:

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript"> 
      function test() 
      { 
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
        for(var i=0; i< links.length; i++) 
        { 
          var link = links[i]; 
          if(link.href) 
          { 
            link.onclick = function() {alert("temp" + i); return false;}; 
          }; 
        }; 
      };
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body onLoad="test()"> 
    <p><a href="javascript.html">test1</a></p> 
    <p><a href="javascript.html">test2</a></p> 
    <p><a href="javascript.html">test3</a></p> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Now, if I click on each link, the browser shows me the same result

> temp3

I used Firebug to profile the code and I figured out that he takes the last value of variable i. My questions are
1st Why does the browser use the always the last value from the variable?
2nd How have I change the source code, so the browser will show me 'temp1', 'temp2', etc. ?

Thanks

Comment: see all [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript"> 
      function test() 
      { 
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
        for(var i=0; i< links.length; i++) 
        { 
          var link = links[i]; 
          if(link.href) 
          { 

              link.onclick = (function(i) { return
                  function() {alert("temp" + i); return false;}; }) (i);
          }; 
        }; 
      };
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body onLoad="test()"> 
    <p><a href="javascript.html">test1</a></p> 
    <p><a href="javascript.html">test2</a></p> 
    <p><a href="javascript.html">test3</a></p> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are dupes in stackoverflow.com. I've got the link available in another tab, so here it is: [Creating closures in loops - common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake)

Here's a dupe: [Stackoverflow.com - Please explain use of javascript closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops) - which gives the two main ways of fixing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Because all answers work, I take the first to mark it as an accepted answer. Hopefully you won't become said or angry.

Comment: I'll live - at least you picked a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `onclick` function only grabs a **reference** to `i`, and not a copy of its value. As the value keeps changing through iterations of the loop, and since the `onclick` function is called after this happens, the value of `i` will always be `links.length`.

To fix this, you want to preserve a **copy** of the variable. A common approach is to wrap the function in another one, that is created and called immediately, passing in the current value of `i`:

```
(function (new_i) {
    link.onclick = function() {alert("temp" + new_i); return false;}; 
})(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Because all answers work, I take the first to mark it as an accepted answer. Hopefully you won't become said or angry.

Comment: @reporter, not sad or angry, but typo.pl was actually first ;)