# Node.JS: How to pass variables to asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-crawler

I'm sure my problem is based on a lack of understanding of asynch programming in node.js but here goes.

For example: I have a list of links I want to crawl. When each asynch request returns I want to know which URL it is for. But, presumably because of race conditions, each request returns with the URL set to the last value in the list.

```
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];
for (link in links) {
    var url = links[link];
    require('request')(url, function() {
        console.log(url);
    });
}
```

Expected output:

```
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
```

Actual output:

```
http://yahoo.com
http://yahoo.com
```

So my question is either:

1. How do I pass url (by value) to the call back function? OR
2. What is the proper way of chaining the HTTP requests so they run sequentially? OR
3. Something else I'm missing?

PS: For 1. I don't want a solution which examines the callback's parameters but a general way of a callback knowing about variables 'from above'.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your `url` variable is not scoped to the `for` loop as JavaScript only supports global and function scoping.  So you need to create a function scope for your `request` call to capture the `url` value in each iteration of the loop by using an immediate function:

```
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];
for (link in links) {
    (function(url) {
        require('request')(url, function() {
            console.log(url);
        });
    })(links[link]);
}
```

BTW, embedding a `require` in the middle of loop isn't good practice.  It should probably be re-written as:

```
var request = require('request');
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];
for (link in links) {
    (function(url) {
        request(url, function() {
            console.log(url);
        });
    })(links[link]);
}
```

Comment: It's not about scope. It's about closures. Lots of other languages don't have block scope yet don't face this issue due to lack of closures.

Comment: The point is that if JavaScript did support block scope, then the closure access to `url` in the callback function of the OP's code would work because each iteration of the loop would get its own `url` variable (like in C#).

Comment: The require is just in there for brevity, in my code all requires are at the beginning.

Comment: If I don't use forloop within the callback it will return url undefined.

Answer (score 13):

Check this [blog](http://samwize.com/2013/09/01/how-you-can-pass-a-variable-into-callback-function-in-node-dot-js/) out. A variable can be passed by using .bind() method. In your case it would be like this:

```
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];
for (link in links) {
var url = links[link];

require('request')(url, function() {

    console.log(this.urlAsy);

}.bind({urlAsy:url}));
}
```

Comment: I like this method more as it's much less verbose than wrapping something in a function.

Comment: This one works without forloop!

Answer (score 7):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747331/243639 for a general discussion of this issue.

I'd suggest something like

```
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];

function createCallback(_url) {
    return function() {
        console.log(_url);
    }
};

for (link in links) {
    var url = links[link];
    require('request')(url, createCallback(url));
}
```

Comment: There are lots of better links to give on StackOverflow to explain the issue. This one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616