# JavaScript: How to pass current value to callback function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to pass current value to callback function. I used [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221769/node-js-how-to-pass-variables-to-asynchronous-callbacks) to work with, but it doesn't work for me.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  (function(_i) {
    var options = {
        //Options here
    };
    console.log(_i); // 0, 1, 2, 3

    LocalImageManager.download(options, function (results, _i) {
      console.log(_i);  //undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined

      //Do stuff with results
    });

  }
})(i);
```

The problem is function always works with "i" variable, which is undefined after the loop finished.

Comment: Use IIFE around the `download()`. `LocalImageManager.download(options, function (results, _i) {
    (function (_i) {
        console.log(_i);
        //Do stuff with results
    })(i);
});`

Comment: do not pass it as an argument just use in console.log() and see what happens

Comment: `_i` will be accessible to all nested functions. You don't need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: You have declared `_i` again in `function (results, _i)`, causing `_i` not getting from loop, change  to `function (results)`

Comment: No but it's a good idea to close around it @evolutionxbox

Comment: @Liam - it looks like it has been closed around. It's just the OP has put the closing brackets for the IIFE in the wrong place.

Comment: what does LocalImageManager.download do/accept as an argument?

Comment: yes, well spotted @evolutionxbox This has multiple problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  (function(_i) {
    var options = {
      //Options here
    };
    console.log(_i); // 0, 1, 2, 3

    LocalImageManager.download(options, function (results) {
      console.log(_i); // 0, 1, 2, 3

      //Do stuff with results
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the definition of `LocalImageManager.download` because your callback method is calling from there only. You can send the value of `_i` in different parameter or with options you passed in function and use at the time of calling the callback method.