# Incorrectly passing callback parameter inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, parameter-passing

I have a variable `id` that is generate in a `for` loop.  For some reason, the `id` changes from 0 to 1 when it is passed in a `callback`.  My guess is that I am passing the `id` parameter incorrectly.

```
    refreshMenu: function(mods, callback){
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu'), 
            ul = document.createElement('ul');

    menu.innerHTML = ''; 
    menu.appendChild(ul);

    for(var id = 0; id < mods.length; id++){
        var li = document.createElement('li'), 
        that = this;


            ul.appendChild(li);

            li.setAttribute('id', id);
            li.innerHTML = mods[id].get('name');

            console.log(id); // HERE ---> 0

            li.addEventListener('click', function(){
                that.selectMenu(li, function(){

                    console.log(id); HERE ---> //1 ?

                that.selectList(id - 1);

                });
            }, false);
        }

        callback();
    }, 

    selectList: function(id)
        var activeList = this.activeList();

        console.log(id);

        if (activeList.id == id){
            return;
        } 
        else if (activeList){
            activeList.setAttribute('class', '');
        };

        var target = document.getElementById(id);
        target.setAttribute('class', 'activeList');
    },  

    selectMenu: function(li, callback){
        if(li.className == 'activeMenu') 
            return; 

        var active = document.getElementsByClassName('activeMenu')[0];
        if(active)      
            active.setAttribute('class', '');

        li.setAttribute('class', 'activeMenu');

        callback();
    },
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very common gotcha when building closures within *for* loops.  All of the functions you're creating refer to the same *id* variable, and the *for* loop **mutates** the variable.

One simple way to fix this: make a helper function that creates these functions, and have the helper take its own parameter.

```
// In the body of the for loop ...
var makeClickFunction = function (li, id) {
    return function (){
        that.selectMenu(li, function(){
                               console.log(id);
                               that.selectList(id - 1);
                            });
    };
};
li.addEventListener('click', makeClickFunction(li, id));
```

The helper's binding of its *id* argument shadows that of the *for* loop, and this is a good thing!  We're intentionally doing this.  We also capture *li*, since it too needs to be held.

Later, we call *makeClickFunction*, passing in the current value within the *for* loop.  *for* will continue to mutate its *id*, but that's ok: that mutation has no relationship to the behavior on *makeClickFunction*'s closures.

Comment: Note that you also need to pass `li` and `that` into the helper function.

Comment: thanks. this makes much more sense.  you forgot the closing brackers for `that.selectMenu` though. i.e.  `});`

Comment: Thanks to both slebetman and user155300; the answer should be corrected now.  I don't believe *that* has to be re-captured by the closure; it appears to stay constant (or at the very least, reassigned to the same value) throughout the loop.

Comment: @dyoo: It depends on where you declare the `makeClickFunction`. If you declare it within the same closure then `that` does not need to be passed. But if it is declared elsewhere outside of the closure then you need to pass in `that`. I was assuming it was declared elsewhere. Missed the comment about it being declared in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `id` has been already changed before the callback is called, so if you want the correct id value when the callback being called, you need the closure.

```
        li.addEventListener('click', function(){
            that.selectMenu(li, function(){

                console.log(id); HERE ---> //1 ?

            that.selectList(id - 1);

            });
        }, false);
```

==>

```
li.addEventListener('click', 
(function(li,that,id){
    return function(){
        that.selectMenu(li, function(){
        console.log(id); 
        that.selectList(id - 1);
        })
    }
})(li,that,id),
false);
```

Comment: it says `undefined is not a function`.  Also you forgot 1 ending bracket for `addEventListener`.

Comment: That's not really creating a closure yet. It should end in `})(li,this,id));` though to be clearer I'd prefer if the inner variables have different names so that it's clear that you are trying to break the closure.

Comment: Also the explanation is wrong. It should be `The variable id is shared by the callbacks because it is captured in a closure, so if you want the correct id in the callback, you need to break the closure.`

Comment: @user1555300, the `id` is changed by the `id++`, the `id` that you use in the loop and the callbacks refer to a same object if you don't use closure.