# How can I pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
>   [Please explain the use of JavaScript closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops)

```
for (var i = 0; i < pois.length; i++) {
    pois[i].marker.addEventListener('dblclick', function (data) {
        var infoWindow = new BMap.InfoWindow(pois[i].address, opts);  
        map.openInfoWindow(infoWindow, map.getCenter());     
    })
}
```

this is my code.
obviously there is an error at here

> new BMap.InfoWindow(pois[i].address, opts);

how can I use pois[i].address in pois[i].marker listener function ?

Comment: which version are you using and what is `pois[]` stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < pois.length; i++) {
    setupEventListener(pois[i]);
}

function setupEventListener(obj) {
    var address = pois[i].address;
    obj.marker.addEventListener('dblclick', function (data) {
        var infoWindow = new BMap.InfoWindow(address, opts);  
        map.openInfoWindow(infoWindow, map.getCenter());     
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Closure is so incredible!