# Getting the right index of an object in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a list of nodes and I am going to draw each node using a raphael object. I have the following loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<curNodes.length; i++){
    var node = curNodes[i];
    var obj = paper.rect(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.width, node.getHeight())
   .attr({fill:nodes[i].getColor(), "fill-opacity": 0.6})
   .click(function(e){ onMouseClicked(i,e); });
}
```

on click, I want to call a function which can view some data associated with 'i' th element of curNodes array. However, all the time the last 'i' is passed to this function. my function is:

```
var onMouseClicked = function(i, event){
switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
        this.attr({title: curNodes[i].name});
        break;
    }
}
```

How should I access the correct index when calling a function?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.click((function (i) {
    return function (e) {
        onMouseClicked(i,e);
    };
})(i));
```

Like you noticed, the value of `i` (or the parameter in your function) is the last index from the `for` loop. This is because the `click` event doesn't happen immediately - the binding does, but the value of `i` is not captured. By the time the `click` handler actually is executed (when the `click` event is triggered in whatever way), the `for` loop has completed (a long time ago), and the value of `i` is the final value of the loop. You can capture the value of `i` with a closure like the above.

Although I know another way of handling, cleaner in my opinion, is to use:

```
.click(clickHandler(i));

function clickHandler(index) {
    return function (e) {
        onMouseClicked(i, e);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) variable `i`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < curNodes.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        var node = curNodes[i];
        var obj = paper.rect(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.width,
                node.getHeight()).attr({
                    fill : nodes[i].getColor(),
                    "fill-opacity" : 0.6
                }).click(function(e) {
                    onMouseClicked(i, e);
                });
    })(i);
}
```