# setTimeout not working. Console says latLng is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make my overlays appear more slowly instead of all at the same time. The code works perfectly until I add setTimeout. When I try to run it, console says that latLng is not defined.

After searching, I see a lot of people have had similar problems but none of them seem to answer my question.

Here's the function. Let me know if you need more of the code.

```
function getAndDrop() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'php/locationarray.php',
        success : function(data) {
            latLng = data.split(" ");

            for ( i = 0; i < latLng.length; i++) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                var loc = latLng[i].split("|");
                if (marker.length > maxOverlays)
                    clearSingleOverlay();
                addMarker(loc[0], loc[1]);
                }, i*200);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: latLng is defined as a global above. It was local. I made it global in an attempt to debug

Comment: @IvanL latLng contains space separated coordinates. I don't think that can be the problem because it ran perfectly without the setTimeout(). When setTimeout() is removed, it functions as I'd expect. It drops all the overlays so faster that it seems like they all appear at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a closure:

```
  success : function(data) {
    var latLng = data.split(" ");

    for ( i = 0; i < latLng.length; i++) {
        (function(LL){


          setTimeout(function(){
            var loc = LL.split("|");
            if (marker.length > maxOverlays)
              clearSingleOverlay();
              addMarker(loc[0], loc[1]);
            }, i*200);


        })(latLng[i]);

    }
}
```

read here for clarification: [Please explain the use of JavaScript closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops)

ps. you should create a dedicated function to handle processing in the loop:

ie: for (...) handleCurrent();

Answer (score -1):

That is because `latLng` is not available in the closure. Could you try adding `var` before the `latLng` declaration:

```
success : function(data) {
    var latLng = data.split(" ");

    for ( i = 0; i < latLng.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        var loc = latLng[i].split("|");
        if (marker.length > maxOverlays)
            clearSingleOverlay();
        addMarker(loc[0], loc[1]);
        }, i*200);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how it was originally. I made it global in an attempt to debug

Comment: > latLng is not available in the closure. Isn't it? Define variable without `var` keyword just makes it defined in `window` context (i.e. global). Unless you don't use strict mode.