# Serving A Batch Of Dynamic Pages

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a few documentation pages I want to serve. Instead of writing something like the following, I want to essentially server them all without writing this code for every page:

```
jade.renderFile("/documentation/gettingStarted", {}, function(err, str) {
    if(err) throw err;
    response.send(str);
});
```

I also would like a simple "Next Page" at the bottom of these pages, with order defined in the following array:

```
var pages = ["installation", "gettingStarted"];
```

The part I'm stuck on is that iterating through each page in my array with `app.get`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    var pagePath = "documentation/" + pages[i];

    app.get("/" + pagePath, function(request, response) {
        jade.renderFile(pagePath + ".jade", {}, function(err, str) {
            if(err) throw err;
            response.send(str);
        });
    });
}
```

With the block above I would hope that it would server pages on the following requests:

- `/documentation/installation`
- `/documentation/gettingStarted`

It works for one page, but due to the fact `jade.renderFile(...)` is called on GET, it will simply use the variables left over from the initialisation, meaning both pages will only return the last page (gettingStarted) because `pagePath` will be kept the same for both requests.

Is there anyway to serve a bunch of files dynamically? Is it required to make call `app.get` for every individual page?

Comment: To learn how to make your loop work, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3572616/711902. But don't use a for loop in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a request parameter. http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params

```
var pages = ['installation', 'gettingStarted'];

app.get('/documentation/:page', function(req, res, next) {
    var page = req.params.page;

    if (pages.indexOf(page) === -1) return next();

    jade.renderFile('documentation/' + page + '.jade', {
        pages: pages,
        nextPage: pages[pages.indexOf(page) + 1]
    }, function(err, str) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(str);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I know to user the parameters feature.

Answer (score 1):

Trevor Dixon pointed to - How to use closures. Thanks.

The problem in your code is that the callback function passed to app.get references a variable from outer scope, ie pagePath, which is changed in the next iteration of the loop. Closures are good to sort it out.

```
for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    var pagePath = "documentation/" + pages[i];

    app.get("/" + pagePath, 
        function(myPagePath){ //closure function recieving pagePath different for each iteration
            return function(request, response) { //return a new function
                jade.renderFile(myPagePath + ".jade", {}, function(err, str) { //myPagePath is a my own copy of pagePath
                if(err) throw err;
                response.send(str);
            });
        }(pagePath) //lets pass value of pagePath from current iteration
    );
}
```

We create a new callback function for every iteration using the 'return function' statement, which accesses myPagePath from its immediate parent scope. Refer to Trevor's link for more on closures.