# How to work with a large number of files and streams in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am working on a small node project which requires copying and ungzipping a number of files of various sizes. I've been trying to use async.eachSeries to take care of it, but it is not working out. The files are created but the pipe out the wr ends up writing to multiple different files regardless of which file it should end up in.

```
     fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
       async.eachSeries(files, function (file, callback) {
         var wr = fs.createWriteStream(file);
         fs.stat(file, function (err, stats) {
           if (err) throw err;
           var stream = fs.createReadStream(file).on('end', function () {
             callback();
           }).pipe(ungzip).pipe(wr);
      });
    }, function () {
      //res.write(concatenated);
      //res.end();
    });
  });
```

I'm still new to node so any help would be appreciated.

-NQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the solution is to use a closure.

The problem in your code is that the callback function passed to fs.stat references a variable from outer scope, ie wr, which is changed in the next iteration of the loop. Closures are good to sort it out.

```
fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
   async.eachSeries(files, function (file, callback) {
       var wr = fs.createWriteStream(file);
       fs.stat(file, function(myWr){
           return function (err, stats) {
               if (err) throw err;
               var stream = fs.createReadStream(file).on('end', function () {
                   callback();
               }).pipe(ungzip).pipe(myWr);
           }
       }(wr));
   }, function () {
   //res.write(concatenated);
   //res.end();}
   });
});
```

Refer [Please explain the use of JavaScript closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616) and [Serving A Batch Of Dynamic Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754286/serving-a-batch-of-dynamic-pages/18757890#18757890) for more on closures.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look robinkc! I'm having an issue implementing your changes. The destination files are created, but data is never streamed to them.

Comment: BTW, Are you trying to create read and write streams on the same file?  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(file); //write stream on file.  fs.createReadStream(file). // read stream on file. And lter pipe it to its own write stream. My suggestion would be to use a destination dir. I am modifying the answer now.