# JavaScript example from MIT open course

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain how this gets 50, and how does the algorithm works. Thanks.

```
var multipliers = function makeMultipliers (max) { 
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
        result.push (function (x) {return x * i;}); 
    return result;
}

multipliers(10) [2] (5)
???
```

what’s the value?

50, not 5

can you fix it?

Source: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-170-software-studio-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT6_170S13_35-java-fn-cls.pdf

page 30

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a scope issue. By the time the last function is called, `i` is where it was last seen at that scope last which would be 10. You can prevent this with a closure.

```
function multipliers(max){
  var a = [];
  for(var i=0; i<max; i++){
    (function(i){
      a.push(function(x){return x*i});
    })(i);
  }
  return a;
}
```

In this case, the closure is a self-executing function that scopes off `i` at each step of the loop. If this did not happen the scope would go to the `multipliers` function itself. Since the loop has already completed by the time you are calling the function which you pass `5` to, which happens to be at step `2` of the Array that `multipliers` returns, `i` has already reached `10`. Obviously, 10*5 is 50. When the closure is used `i`s last position is `2` within the scope it is in, giving you the result that is sought. 5*2 = 10.

```
console.log(multipliers(10)[2](5));
```

Comment: Technically it's a closure issue. Because of closures the variable `i` is shared across all the functions in `a` (that's what closures do - they share stack frames). You can prevent this by ***breaking the closure***.

Comment: Call it whatever you want. In this case the scope of `i` creates the undesired results.

Comment: Yeah. But you don't prevent it with a closure - the closure is the SOURCE of your scope problem. You prevent it by breaking the closure. You break a closure by passing via function argument.

Comment: You are  really scoping off `i`, because you are passing that argument into the self-executing function where it is closed off. Multiple books I have read taught me this. I have never heard this breaking the closure term, myself.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it's doing. However, this mechanism is not called a "closure". The closure is the mechanism that causes `i` to be shared in the first place. Your scoping off the `i` is intended remove it from the closure.

Comment: This answer is technically about something else but to answer the question I had to explain what a closure is. See this for an explanation of what closures are: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26063201/167735

Comment: In this case the Anonymous self-executing function refers to the independent var `i` in the for loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: That mozilla doc is impercise about breaking the closure. Technically it's correct that it's using a function factory to break the closure. Technically it's even correct to say use more closure because every function in javascript is a closure. But it should have been more specific in saying that what it means is to create a function where its closure only encloses the global scope. But it's wrong to say that that's the reason the solution works.

Comment: Cool. An explanation from an unanswered Stack Overflow question. Still waiting for that "breaking the closure" link. What if code was not in a function? Where would this closure that you would be breaking be? Would it be at the global scope, even though there would be no closure?

Comment: What link are you waiting for? That the mechanism for why `i` is shared accross functions called a "closure"? It's in the mozilla doc you linked to.

Comment: Code not inside function:  `for(var i=0,l=someArray.length; i<l; i++){(function(i){ /* where would closure you break be? */ })(i)}`

Answer (score 0):

This code creates an array of functions which will incorrectly all end up referring to the final value of `i`, but which are intended to freeze the value of `i` during each iteration.

To fix it you simply could add a level of locality to the iteration variable by embedding a new local variable that freezes the value of `i` within another function. For example, below the existing local variable `i` is passed into the dummy function as an argument, and the value of `i` at that instant is frozen into the new local variable `i` which is independent of the original `i` and not changed by the subsequent iterations of the original `i`.

```
result.push (function (x) {return x * i;})

result.push((function(i) {
    return function (x) {return x * i;};
})(i));
```