# JavaScript closure saving state

Tags: javascript, closures

I am reading over this code and the article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures) about closures:

```
function outer() {

    var reference = 0;

    return function() {
        reference += 1;
        return reference;
    }
}

var x = outer();
x();
x()
x()
console.dir( x() );
```

Yet, I am baffled at how this code remembers state. For some reason the author of the code decided to name a variable `reference`. Only thing that comes to mind is the, "physical address" meaning in this context.

When I see the lines of code from `var x = ...`
I am thinking the following:

1. assign the anonymous function to the variable x. At this time of execution the `reference` variable of the outer function is 0 and so is it in the inner function
2. execute the inner function adding the variable `reference` to 1 then I loose track

From running the code all I can see is that the inner function creates some type of reference/pointer ,if you will, to the outer functions `reference` variable which is updated each time the closure is executed. For some reason the `reference` variable's value persists upon further execution almost like a static variable in php. Is this why MDN says that a closure "remembers" its environment?

Any step by step explanation would help.

Comment: If you want to see a more technical discussion of how closures work at the memory level see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061856/javascript-cant-access-private-properties/26063201#26063201

Comment: Well I looked over the wikipedia article on closures and this line made sense with my line of thinking: " A closure—unlike a plain function—allows the function to access those captured variables through the closure's reference to them, even when the function is invoked outside their scope."