# How many closures are created in the following code?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm a beginner and I'm taking an interactive online class. Closures were the topic of discussion today. The following question was asked, "How many closures are created in the following code?".

```
function addUp (c, d) {
  return c + d;
}

function doubleDown (c) {
  return addUp(c, c);
}
```

I said **two** and my answer was based on [this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation). I was told the answer is **one** closure is created. The reason given was convoluted and obviously didn't make sense to me. I've read over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735129/how-do-javascript-closures-work-at-a-low-level), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491626/where-does-a-javascript-closure-live/37493113#37493113), and [this](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/#ecmascript-closures-implementation) where the following statement is made:
[image]

So my question is where am I going wrong with my interpretation of closures? Any additional resources I can be pointed to will be appreciated.

Comment: The question should probably be "How many functions are *used as* closures in the following code?" As in: which of these two functions make use of capabilities that only closures have

Comment: I would also say 2 based on the "all functions in ecmascript are closures" statement.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your interpretation. If you can explain your choice (and also why 0 might be another suitable answer that's not wrong), that's probably worth much more than saying what they wanted to hear. It's a good question in an oral exam, it's a horrible question in a multiple choice test.

Comment: @Bergi i guess thats not true like that. can you explain why? because was far as i know there is a lexical environment for each function called which has a pointer to its outer environment and if a func does not find a var within its scope it searches within the outer environment. does it it find it not within but within its env. but within the outer (there can be a chain) its a closure.

Comment: @RobinF. By strict definition, It's a closure already when it does have the pointer to the outer environment, not when it uses this chain to lookup a variable. (That sounds like `function() { if (false) return global }` would not be a closure - and would make it an undecidable problem in general even)

Comment: @Bergi makes sense. thanks.