# Regarding function variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript so please understand if the question is a bit naive.
I have heard that functions are also objects in javascript . So that means functions can also have properties like objects. So I tried this :

```
var foo=function(){
        var v1=1;
        console.log(foo.v1);
    };
    foo();
```

The output of this is `undefined`. I dont understand what is happening. So when I declare the variable `v1` in the function `foo` ,according to the result `v1` is not a property of the function-object `foo`.If it is not the former then what is it a property of ? Could some one explain to me what is happening ?

Comment: `v1` is not a property of anything. It is a variable. `foo.v1` and a variable named `v1` in `foo` are unrelated. You can assign to `foo.v1` if you like, or pass `foo` to other functions, etc. like any other object, but variables aren’t reflected in functions’ properties in any way.

Comment: foo.v1 is indeed undefined, all you have defined is a var `v1` in the scope of function foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object properties and variables are not the same thing. Functions can have both local variables (this includes function arguments) and properties:

```
function foo () {
    v1 = 1; // this is a local variable
    return [
        v1,    // local var above
        foo.v2 // object property
    ]
}

foo(); // returns [1,undefined]

foo.v2 = 2;
foo(); // returns [1,2]
```

So you see, functions are indeed objects. But variables inside the function have nothing to do about the fact that functions are objects.

Side note: the fact that functions are first-class objects and that functions can be defined anonymously (without a name) are two different features. In C for example, functions are also first-class objects - that is, you can assign them to function pointers. But in C you can't declare functions without a name.

```
function bar() {}

b = bar; // this demonstrates that functions are first-class objects
c = function(){}; // this demonstrates that functions can be anonymous
```

Comment: Ok so basically the difference between 'normal' objects in javascript and 'function- objects' in javascript is the fact that the latter can have local variables in it. On a side note where are the local variables actually defined, is it in the scope of the function ??

Comment: Yes, it's in the function scope. Though, scope in javascript isn't like it is in C - they can persist even after the function has returned. Look up info on closures.

Comment: See my answer to this question for a deep/detailed discussion of scopes and closures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061856/javascript-cant-access-private-properties/26063201#26063201

Comment: Thank you very much . That really cleared the concepts for me

Answer (score 1):

You're right in Javascript function is a object. You can have attribute in a function object, examples are link length etc.

> according to the result v1 is not a property of the function-object foo.

v1 is just a variable defined in function foo, it is not a attribute.

To add a attribute you could use `foo.v1 = "1"` to add attribute v1 to object foo.

If you use console.log(v1) instead of console.log(foo.v1). You'll see output 1. Here you're accessing a local variable inside a function.

You might think var foo is already a object why can't I access it inside the function? This because these two foo variables are in different scopes. You might want to learn more about function [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you please elaborate on the last sentence, I did not understand it properly