# How clearInterval() clears a timerID inside of a setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, stack, closures, setinterval, clearinterval

I am new to Javascript and have came across to the topic of stack. In the following piece of code (which is simple in order to focus on basics instead of syntax), I can clear timerID inside of my function expression variable. It is quite common to do so, but my question is how the stack is made here? To be more clear, how the order of  things goes on to clear the variable in which the clearer itself lives? And how the "console.log('DONE!')" is called after clearInterval()?

```
function countNumbers(number){
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    number++;
    if(number >= 10){
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log('DONE!');
    }
    else {
      console.log(number);
    }

  },1000)
}
```

Comment: It's called a closure. See my answer to this other question for how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061856/javascript-cant-access-private-properties/26063201#26063201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a inner function is maintaining a reference to a variable of an outer function in JavaScript a *clousure* is formed, that is the members of the outer function is not destroyed when the outer function is done running since it's variables are still being referred from another function.

This is because when a function is executed a new Execution Context is created for that function's environment. It maintains a scope chain and is then pushed to the execution stack in the order of execution.

There is a global Execution context, then the invocation of the `countNumbers` creates its own execution context and finally the execution context of the callback is created. The callback function execution context maintains a pointer to the scope of the `countNumbers` function's execution context which maintains a pointer to the execution context of the global:

[image]

In your case, when the `setInterval()` runs it immediately/synchronously returns the ID and it is set in the `timer` variable. Since the `timer` variable is defined in the scope of the `countNumbers` function the inner/callback function forms a clousure over it. The execution context of the callback can reach and access the `timer` variable through the scope chain.

Now when you run the `setInterval` the callback is queued and executed at the specified interval asynchronously. Due to the clousure formed earlier the callback has access to the `timer` variable declared in the outer function scope, so when the `number` reaches 10 it can use that value of the ID from the outer function scope to cancel the interval.

Comment: Thanks for the precise reply. To enrich the discussion, here is a good explanation of Closure in js. I found it helpful:
[Closures in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @Baran Nazari please accept my answer if you found it useful!