# How Closure gets set in Web API call?

Tags: javascript, closures

I was not getting how a closure  variable gets attached to function ([[Scope]]) when making a Web API request like for timer (serTimeout).

```
function fun() {   
    function log() {console.log(callme) }; 
    console.dir(log); 
    setTimeout( log, 10000);
    const callme = "hi iam"
  }
fun()
```

[image]
function *log* gets access to variable *callme* when const do not get hoisted.

My thinking is that *fun()* is called , it is pushed to call stack , function *log* is then sent to WebAPI timer function , in the mean time *fun* gets run and sets *callme* variable in its execution context. Once Timer is over , fn *log* is pushed to callback queue and event loop after checking if call stack is empty pushes *log* to callstack for execution. I am not able to get the idea when **callme** gets attached to closure **[[Scope]]** of function *log*

Comment: `[[Scope]]` is just a reference to the execution context of the parent function. And as you said, *callme* got added to it (also it does get hoisted, just differently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, `hoisting` is a really bad concept that just happens to be useful. It leads to minunderstandings such as yours. The real way the interpreter works is something like my answer to this related question: [JavaScript function declaration and evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order/3887590#3887590)

For your specific example, you mention:

> when const do not get hoisted

This is not really true. Of course, hoisting does not really exist in the language, it is just a concept programmers created to explain how the language behaves. Let's see how your code is interpreted when we split the parsing into two phases: compilation and execution:

```
function fun() {   
    function log() {console.log(callme) }; 
    console.dir(log); 
    setTimeout( log, 10000);
    const callme = "hi iam"
  }
fun()
```

Compilation phase

1. OK, we have a function definition `fun`, let's parse it's body
2. OK, we have a function definition `log`, let's parse it's body

   1. OK, we're logging a variable `callme`. Note the variable we are using
3. We want to call `log` after 10 seconds, Note the function setTimeout is using
4. We define a constant `callme`

Execution phase

1. OK, we are calling `fun()`

   1. We are declaring a function log(), create an instance of it
   2. We output the definition of `log`
   3. we are calling `setTimeout()`, find a variable/function called `log` - found it, add `log` to event queue
   4. Set the value of `callme` to "hi iam" (note that values cannot be set in compilation phase because it may involve executing code for example if we do `const x = (1).toString()`, const just means we cannot set the value outside of initialisation)
   5. End of function call, we detect that `callme` is used in a closure, attach it
2. 10 seconds pass by, OK event loop detects timeout, call `log()`

   1. We need to log `callme` - found it in a closure, log it.

This is how `callme` gets pulled into `foo`'s closure. If you insist on using the `hoisting` terminology you can say that if there is a closure then const gets hoisted.

But you don't really need to know all the corner-cases of when hoisting happens and when it does not if you have as your mental model this two-phase interpretation. I strongly suggest reading the answer linked above to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: it is great explanation , thanks a lot it makes clear understanding now. Just one query since callme variable is not set during compilation phase and in execution phase  step3 , using setTimeout fn forces log function to move from  JS environment to webAPI world where timer exist and then callme is set to "hi i am" and fun() is removed from callstack. So how log has access to callme in execution phase step 2

Comment: As long as there's a closure a function or variable is not removed from the stack. Instead it is referenced counted and will be deleted eventually by the garbage collector. See my answer to this question for a more detailed explanation of the memory model for closures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061856/javascript-cant-access-private-properties/26063201#26063201 (it's rather unfortunate that some of my most detailed answers were written as tangents to questions that are not directly about that topic making them hard to find even for me)