# JavaScript Closures and Block-Scoped Variables In Loop Memory Management

Tags: javascript, memory-management, closures, heap-memory, local-variables

This question is a few different (I think related) questions, which I give below, but broadly I am trying to understand a code piece from David Flanagan's O'Reilly book on JavaScript that gives an example as using a loop for creating closures as unintended:

```
function constfuncs() {
    let funcs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        funcs[i] = () => i;
    }
    return funcs;
}

let funcs = constfuncs();
funcs[5]() //10, rather than 5
```

The above code example intends to have each element of the `funcs` array be a function that can be called without arguments to return a value numerically equivalent to its index in `funcs`; however, it does not succeed at doing this. I think I largely understand why this is: `var i`, because it is declared using `var`, is scoped to the function `constfuncs`, rather than the block of that `for` loop, and so hence it is the same `i` being used by each function stored in `funcs`, and `i` ends as `10` in that loop, so hence any of the ten returned functions in `funcs` will always evaluate to `10` when called.

On the next page of the book, it's stated that to fix the above, it's a one-line change: simply have `i` be block-scoped, and so use `let i` instead of `var i` in that `for` loop, as follows:

```
function constfuncs() {
    let funcs = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        funcs[i] = () => i;
    }
    return funcs;
}

let funcs = constfuncs();
funcs[5]() //is now 5, as desired
```

What I don't understand, however, is how this fixes the problem. `i` to me seems to still exist only once, yet each of the ten created functions appears to have access to its own version/copy of `i` in memory. If a new block-scoped local variable was declared in the `for` loop that was assigned the value of `i` on each iteration prior to then being used instead of `i` as the value each function of `funcs` returned, then perhaps it would make more sense to me, if it is the case that block-scoped local variables declared in a loop are redeclared (as using new memory) on each iteration; but even so, `i` is not and yet the above still works as desired. This leads me to my questions:

1. How are closures managed in memory in JavaScript? I am fairly new to JS and closures, and am used to languages having a stack and heap.
2. Does the act of defining a closure cause a copying of memory from the stack to the heap to save outer local variables for use by that closure? This is because a closure seems to defy local variables only being stored on the stack, as it can still access them.
3. Are block-scoped local variables re-created in memory (at a different memory location each time) for each iteration of an outer loop they are declared in?
4. If possible yes to 3., is this influenced at all by whether a closure is used (ie, only created once in memory across loop iterations as the general case, but on each loop iteration if a closure has that local block variable in scope for it)?
5. By "binding", do we mean a distinct location for a variable or constant in memory? I ask as the book states in its explanation for the above solution that "Because `let` and `const` are block scoped, each iteration of the loop defines a scope that is independent of the scopes for all other iterations, and each of these scopes has its own independent binding of `i`."

Questions 1-2 are related, as are 3-4; and all are related to the above example. Any other thoughts for explaining why the second approach above (with `let i`) succeeds in fixing the solution are welcome.

Comment: I have read an answer posted by @slebetman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061856/javascript-cant-access-private-properties/26063201#26063201), but it simply describes a closure as storing outside local variables for another stack frame "somewhere in RAM".

Comment: [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612)

Comment: I suggest to create separate questions, each one focused on only one of your concerns. _(Probably also makes sense to ask the next one only if you have understood the previous ones.)_ If you ask multiple questions at once, people who know only some or one of the answers can not answer, so you need to wait for a person who knows all of them, and is willing to write a long answer (which probably will not happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically I'm not answering any of you questions, but I can explain the part where you wondered "how this fixes the problem":*

Variables declared with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#scoping_rules) in the for-loop initialization **are treated as if they were declared inside the loops "body"**, [by definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#syntax). That is a special behavior of for-loops with `let`.

Variables declared with `var` on the other hand have the same scope as where the for-loop is defined (i.e. outside of the loops "body").

#### Examples

So if you would declare the `let i` **outside** the for-loop, you would get the wrong value `10` again (as you expected):

```
function constfuncs(){
    let funcs = [];
    let i;
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        funcs[ i ] = function(){
            return i;
        };
    }
    return funcs;
}
```

On the other hand, even if you keep the `var` inside the loop initialization, but declare a **new variable** with `let` inside the loops body, you would get the desired value `5`:

```
function constfuncs(){
    let funcs = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        let value = i;            // <-- new variable in every iteration
        funcs[ i ] = () => value;
    }
    return funcs;
}
```

#### Remarks

The newer `let` declaration is specifically designed for this behavior, because people tended to be confused about the behavior of `var`.

*(I case you wonder: IMO `let` has too many special cases. `let` makes the behavior more intuitive when you *don't* think about it, but more complicated if you want to understand it. But it still solves important flaws of `var`.)*