# javascript closure for_loop

Tags: javascript, closures

I have been stuck on this for a while. I had also threw in a debugger to see what is actually happening. I think it is something related to closure but not 100% sure.

```
var names = [ "roy", "nick" ];
var ids = [0, 1];
var people = [];

for ( i in names ){
    people.push({
        name: names[i],
        id: ids[i]
    })
    people[i].ages = {
        this_year: function(){
            var ages = [10, 11];
            return ages[i];
        }
    }
}
console.log(people[0].ages.this_year()); // why not 10
```

---

Tried using function arguments as suggest by @slebetman, however, i intend to invoke the function later so this wouldn't work..

```
var names = [ "roy", "nick" ];
var ids = [0, 1];
var people = [];

for ( i in names ){
    people.push({
        name: names[i],
        id: ids[i]
    })
    people[i].ages = {
        this_year: (function(x){
            var ages = [10, 11];
            return ages[x];
        })(i)
    }
}
console.log(people[0].ages.this_year); // 10
console.log(people[0].ages.this_year()); // not a function
```

Comment: Yes, you've created a closure. All the functions you created in the for loop shares ONE SINGLE VARIABLE called `i`. And the value of `i` at the end of the loop is `1`

Comment: @slebetman, yes, I can see that happening with the debugger, but why doesn't it create the function when i = 0, instead of creating the function at the end of the loop

Comment: if you were to fix the code so that it will return 10 for people[0].ages.this_year(), how would you fix it??

Comment: Wrap it in another function. See my answer in the duplicate question. The ONLY way to break a closure in javascript is by passing values via function argument.

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops#answer-3572616

Comment: I'm assuming this is an exercise ...`for ( i in names )` sets `i` to be each element of the `names` array in turn, not an index.  Replace it with a more traditional `for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++)` loop.  The closure thing use slebetman's approach or store the value of `i` in your ages object and use that to index `ages`.  (i.e. `index: i, this_year ... return ages[this.index];` ... `

Comment: @slebetman, I tried using the function arguments, while it does give me a return of 10 for people[0].ages.this_year, it isn't something I desire. I need the this_year to be a function where I can invoke later using people[0].ages.this_year().

Comment: @Tibrogargan, sorry, I couldn't understand your third sentence. I can see how i is represented as an index in my original code and how i could write it using the traditional loop method. I don't understand the rest of your comment. Could you elaborate a bit more plz? Thx

Comment: `i` is NOT an index, it is an element value. `for ( i in names )` does not make `i` take the values `0, 1, 2 etc` it will literally take the values `"roy", "nick"` etc.  Since both `names` and `ids` are arrays, neither of them have properties called `roy` or `nick`

Comment: @Tibrogargan, when I throw a debugger in the loop, it does show i is "0" to "1".. I am very confused now

Comment: Your `ages` property is an object that contains a single property called `this_year` that is a closure defined as `function() { var ages[10, 11]; return ages[i];`  At no time in that function is the variable `i` declared, so it will not exist when the function runs (it will be undefined).  You could add a second property to the object stored in `ages` that stored the value of `i` (i.e. `ages: { index: i, this_year: ... `.  This would allow you to access it in the closure as `this.index`.  It's odd, since you could just do `{ value: ages[i] }` - which is why I think it's an exercise

Comment: Ahh yeah, my bad.  Too many new things in javascript.  Yes, the `for .. in` construct on arrays iterates through each index as if it was a named property.

Comment: Probably should clarify some more.  `i` does exist and will exist every time you access `this_year` simply because `this_year` creates a reference to it.  The problem is that it's going to have the last value it took (11) every time you access `this_year`.  It's defined, just not useful - every instance of `this_year` is going to have a reference to the same `i`

Comment: @Yes: See the duplicate question. You pass `i` as a function to a function that returns a function: `(function(z){return function(){return ages[z]}})(i)`