# How to return the index of a nodelist using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, nodelist

I have something that I would like to convert from jquery to js.

I am using js to create 12 li elements which when clicked gets the index number, in jquery I used the .index() function to achieve this,

```
var month = $(".calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month"),
    startMonth;

$(month).on('click', function () {
    startMonth = $(this).index() + 1;
});
```

How would I do this is vanilla js, I have gotten as far as

```
var month = document.querySelectorAll(".calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month"),
    startMonth;

for (var i=0; i<month.length; i++) {       
    month[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        startMonth = this; //returns full html element, just need index number
    });
}
```

Comment: startMonth = i returns 12, i need it to return the index of the element clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the index in the element.

```js
var month = document.querySelectorAll(".calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month"),
    startMonth;

for (var i=0; i<month.length; i++) {
    month[i].index = i;
 
    month[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert(this.index+1);
    });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month">Jan</li>
  <li class="calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month">Feb</li>
  <li class="calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month">March</li>
  <li class="calenderApp__calender__allMonths__month">Apr</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what exactly month[i].index = i; is doing?

Comment: Well it's storing `i` into `month[i].index` :) So when you click on `month[i]`, all you have to do is recall `this.index`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the traditional closure in a loop problem. Indeed, this use case was the original use case that people asked about before ajax became popular. As such you can use the traditional solution:

```
for (var i=0; i<month.length; i++) {
    (function(j){
        month[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            startMonth = j; // j is the captured value of i
        });
    })(i); // capture value of `i` here to break closure
}
```

As for why this happens read this: [Please explain the use of JavaScript closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616) or any of the dozens of pages about closures in loops on SO or elsewhere.