# addEventListener not working as intended inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am trying to make a calendar/schedule in JS, and the method `addEventListener` used on a scheduled event returns the same event id, when it should return the id of the clicked event.

This is the function I have at the moment:

```
monthStart = date.clone().subtract(1, 'months').endOf 'month'
monthEnd = parseInt date.clone().endOf('month').format 'DD'
daysContainer = @createElement 'div', 'calendar__days'

for i in [1..monthEnd]
  day = monthStart.add 1, 'day'
  current = day.format 'DD-MM-YYYY'

  line = @createElement 'div', 'calendar__line'
  line.classList.add 'line--today' if current == @current.format 'DD-MM-YYYY'

  header = @createElement 'div', 'line__header'
  header.appendChild @createElement 'h1', 'line__date', day.format 'DD'
  header.appendChild @createElement 'span', 'line__day', day.format 'dd'
  events = @createElement 'div', 'line__events'

  events_data = @parseEventsPerDay current
  for event in events_data
    event_block = @createElement 'div', 'event'
    x = event.id
    event_block.addEventListener 'click',  => console.log event.id <<---------- this line returns always the same id
    event_container = @createElement 'div', 'event__container'
    event_block.appendChild @createElement 'div', 'event__bbg' + ' ' + @resolveColor 'bg', event.type
    event_container.appendChild @createElement 'div', 'event__timeinterval', event.timeStart + ' - ' + event.timeEnd
    event_container.appendChild @createElement 'div', 'event__content'  + ' ' + @resolveColor('link', event.type), event.title

    event_block.appendChild event_container
    events.appendChild event_block

  line.appendChild events
  line.appendChild header
  line.appendChild events
  daysContainer.appendChild line

@el.appendChild daysContainer
```

Also any ideas, tips, tutorials for the entire project, for my code, are welcome.

Comment: Use closure in the loop for the `addEventListener`. [More informations here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops)

Comment: @Robiseb I've tried this: (() -> console.log event.id ) it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @robiseb mentioned in a comment, you need to use closures to ensure that the current event is a local variable inside the closure of the loop, rather than a global variable.

For details on closures, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Coffeescript supplies us with the `do` keyword to make this easier. See the last example in the [loops and comprehensions coffee docs](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).

```coffee
for event in events_data
  do(event) ->
    event_block = @createElement 'div', 'event'
    x = event.id
    event_block.addEventListener 'click',  => console.log event.id
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.